# How to stop Mail.app filling up with downloaded mail

Tags: icloud, mail.app, ms-office, gmail

I have started using MS Outlook for mail and calendar management because of its tight integration and ease of handling mail. I have a Gmail account an iCloud account and a POP account with an Australian ISP. I sometimes have to open the old Mail.app to find an older piece of mail and when I do this tons of duplicate emails start rolling into the program. It’s a waste of time going through and deleting them as I have already dealt with them in Outlook. Should I archive all the old mail in Mail.app and then not use that app again or is there a better approach to this?

Comment: You can stop auto download/check of new mail in account setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you move all your existing e-mails from Mail to Outlook, instead of having to switch between two applications to do it? [This article](https://kb.intermedia.net/article/2135) suggests that Outlook might be able to do that directly from your hard drive.

As @Pratika Rana pointed out in the comments, you can also turn off autodownload of e-mails by account: in the Mail preferences (`Mail -> Preferences...` in the menu bar), select the account you want to modify and select the `Advanced` tab. The `Include when automatically checking for new messages` should turn off *automatic* downloading of new e-mails, while leaving your account active and existing e-mails untouched, while still giving you the option to download new e-mails manually if you go back to using Mail in the future.